# How to change the index of all the 1 in an 2d numpy array which only has 0s and 1s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array(arr) which only has 0s and 1s.

For example, a 2d numpy array in shape(h,w).

I want to resize the array to shape(h // scale, w // scale), and I need to keep all the 1s.

```py
# arr is a 2d numpy array
h, w = arr.shape
h_new, w_new = h // scale, w // scale
arr_new = np.zeros((h_new, w_new))
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if arr[i, j] == 1:
            arr_new[i // scale, j // scale] = 1
```

For example, a 2d array like this, and scale=2:

```
[
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1]
]
```

After runnung the code, arr_new will be:

```
[
    [1,0],
    [1,1]
]
```

the change of all the 1s' coordinates:

```
(1,1) -> (0,0)
(2,0) -> (1,0)
(2,3) -> (1,1)
(3,3) -> (1,1)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you resize without dropping some elements, which can happen to be 1s?

Comment: Can you please share an example of what the input and the expected output might look like.

Comment: Depending on what `scale` is, you are just overwriting the same elements over and over.

Comment: I added an example, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reshape the array by splitting each dimension to grid `(SIZE // SCALE, SCALE)`. Next reduce all dimensions of size SCALE using `max()` to let `1` dominate the SCALExSCALE cell.

```
arr.reshape(h//scale, scale, w // scale, scale).max(axis=(1,3))
```

Note that this solution requires shape of `array` to be multiplicity os `(scale, scale)`.